# How to render grayscale numpy array as PyQt6 QImage?

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt6, qimage, qpixmap

Given a variable blurmap that is a grayscale 1440x1080 numpy array that when saved with imageio results in this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxKha.jpg

What is causing PyQt to render it like this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pnlP.png

The relevant code to load the data as a QImage/QPixmap is as follows:

```
h, w = blurmap.shape
self.blurmap = QtGui.QImage(blurmap, w, h, QtGui.QImage.Format.Format_Grayscale8)
self.image_3.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(self.blurmap))
```

I've tried various formats and even the above code is already from other questions that have asked similar problems, but I can't seem to get it to render correctly no matter what I do. I am able to load RGB888 files in the same project with slight variation to the code but this greyscale image is not working at all. For example here is the relevant code for loading the RGB888 images which I have also tried to adapt for the grayscale image to no avail:

```
h, w, c = self.rawInput.shape
bytesPerLine = 3 * w
self.baseImg = QtGui.QImage(self.rawInput.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format.Format_RGB888)
self.image_1.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(self.baseImg))
```

As far as I'm aware the only difference is with the bytesPerLine variable added which I'm to believe is simply taking into account the 3 channels of the RGB image, which this grayscale should not require

Comment: There's another difference: in your second example you're using the `data` attribute of the array, while in the first one you're directly using the array. Change to `QImage(blurmap.data, ...)`.

Comment: Oh dang I completely missed that, unfortunately it doesn't seem to have any effect and I'm still getting the same result when it's rendered in the UI - it's looking like I may have to simply render the image to a jpg or something along those lines and open it that way which isn't ideal

Comment: It would also important to know how you create the array. I'd suggest you to provide a basic [mre] that shows the result you get, based on the image you're providing, because it's possible that you're using the wrong type (maybe int32 instead of int8).

Comment: That assumption was actually right on the money - it was a float64 image that I just needed to convert to uint8 first - I'll make sure to provide more in the future so stuff like that can be caught, thanks so much!

Comment: Why not close the question by answering your own question?

Comment: @Tisaric Good. Please be aware that questions that are not reproducible are considered off topic in StackOverflow. I've already marked yours as such, caused by: 1. the missing `data` attribute (possible *typo*) and 2. the fact that we didn't know about the wrong data type (not reproducible); it may be probably closed sooner or later anyway. Your options now are to either close/delete the question on your own, or [edit] the question including a [mre], and providing a proper answer using the "Answer your question" button. I would suggest you the latter, as it might be actually useful to others.